# How do I reflect the movement of an armitage on the opposite side, without rotating the Mirror axis?

Tags: armature, reflection, mirror-modifier

It really needs the pictures to explain but essentially I have 2 wings. 1 wing which has a Mirror modifier which reflects to the other side. I'm adding bones to the original wing in order to make a simple flap, however when I rotate that first bone of the armature the wing rotates on the axis (in the middle of the stage), rather than reflecting as if in a mirror and making a realistic flap.

Here it is before rotating:
[image]

And when I rotate you can see it doesn't have the desired effect:
[image]

Any ideas on the best way to get this to reflect properly when I move the bone?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't count on a *Mirror* modifier to mirror the wing movement, instead apply the *Mirror* modifier, mirror the armature and use a *Copy Rotation* constraint on the opposite bone, so that when you move your bone, the other follows:

[image]

Comment: OK cool will look into that. Sorry super noob here. Is there a quick way to make the mirrored wing 'a real object' rather than a reflection

Comment: Apply the Mirror modifier